# Changing explorer.exe's default path makes explorer processes stay open

Tags: windows-8, windows-explorer, process

I wanted to change File Explorer's default folder to My Computer, using either:

```
%windir%\explorer.exe ::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}
```

or

```
%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe shell:MyComputerFolder
```

but when I change the shortcut's Target and try to close Explorer, the process stays open.

[image: Explorer.exe processes]

I'm assuming it's because I'm opening a separate instance of explorer.exe every time, but why doesn't it close when I click the close button? I haven't heard anyone mentioning this in the article's I've read. Is there a way around this, besides using an alternative Explorer or `Win+E`?

Comment: phone the MS support about the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have had similar issues with 3rd party apps spawning explorer and not exiting properly.  Never found a solution but have a PS1 workaround that kills stray explorer sessions, skipping the desktop, which is **usually** the largest one.

Kill_Stray_Explorer.ps1

```
Get-Process explorer | Sort-Object -descending CPU | Select-Object -Skip 1 ID | ForEach-Object -Process {Stop-Process -Id $_.ID}
#
```

Task scheduler it to run every so often or better yet, paste this full command into a shortcut so it can be double clicked.

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -nologo -noninteractive -WindowStyle Hidden -command "& {C:\Kill_Stray_Explorer.ps1}"
```